# Windows XP's appearance is messed up

Tags: windows, windows-xp, display, colors

For some reason, the appearance of my computer has gone haywire. See picture below. I have not downloaded anything and as you can see: the theme is Windows XP.

Help?

[image]

Comment: Looks like it might be in 256-bit (sic) color mode. My kid's games used to do something similar. Have you tried a reboot?

Comment: It wasn't that. I went to display and color property and it was set to 8-bit. I changed it 32 and all was well. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah meant 8-bit. Been awhile since I had XP (or let the kids play on my computer :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that that the color property in the display box, from the Control Panel box, was set to 8-bit. I selected 32-bit from the dropdown and all was well again.

Comment: Can you guess how did it go to 8-bit setting? Due to a game?